# how to create numeric-style instead of authoryear-style citation call-outs?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

When I write the citations, I get the name of the author and the year, like this "[Alagarasi(2011)]", but I want the citation call-out to be numeric, say, "[2]".

```
\documentclass[10pt,‌​twoside,openright]{re‌​port} 
    \usepackage[phd]{edmaths}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}


    \bibliographystyle{apsrev}
    \bibliography{reference}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: The `>` markdown is for formatting quotations, in order to format code, you should use code sample markdown. Simply highlight the code and press ctrl+k, or use the code sample button (fifth from the left, the one that looks like {})

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What document class are you using? Can you give a pointer to `edmaths.sty`?

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{plain}` instead of `apsrev` may do what you want.

Comment: Please always post compilable code. Numerical labels are default.

Comment: @Marijn - The `plain` bibliography style formats the bibliographic entries rather differently from the `apsrev` style. Presumably, the OP is using `apsrev` for a reason; switching to a different bibliography style mainly because of the formatting of the citation call-outs seems like questionable advice. At least, you should point out that the OP should expect major changes in the way the bibliographic entries are formatted.

Comment: @Mico in my comment I said that it may do what the OP wants, implying that it also may not do what s/he wants. It could be that `apsrev` was just copied from somewhere as part of an example. It could also be that using `apsrev` was intentional, but `plain` is also acceptable for the OP. In any case, it's easy to try out and revert if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the `apsrev` bibliography style was created with the `makebst` utility, which was written by the author of the `natbib` citation management package. Hence, adding the instruction

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

to the preamble will give you numeric style citation call-outs.